# What does the moment of severing feel like?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

We have descriptions of what it feels like once a person has been severed or burned out, but do we have descriptions of what the act of severing feels like when it occurs?

We know that a person cannot be severed until they have touched the True Source for the first time. There has to be something to cut, otherwise it doesn’t do anything.

Examples:

Rand stills 3 sisters at Dumai’s Wells. Two of them pass out, and the third is screaming. They were holding the Power when it occurred.

Siuan and Leane are stilled during the coup, after being put to the question. It’s not clear if they were conscious when they were stilled or not. They would not have been holding the Power when it occurred.

Logain is gentled. Presumably he was conscious, not holding the power when it was done.

Assuming one were awake, what would the instant feel like, if anything? Would the experience be different if one is holding the power vs shielded vs not touching the source?

Comment: I don't think we get any more details in canon beyond simply asserting that it's one of the most painful experiences that can be inflicted on a human being.

Comment: Where is that said? Do you remember?